# Eclipse Missing Constraints Import Package

Tags: java, eclipse

When trying to run my Eclipse Java Project I get the following:

[image: screenshot]

Where do I download these constraints from? And how do I add them to eclipse? I tried googling for 'lucene.document' but wasn't quite sure what I was looking for. I also searched for it in the Eclipse marketplace but nothing came up.

Other similar questions I looked at talked about using the plugins tab to add them in automatically. So I tried going into 'run configurations' > 'plugins' > 'add required plug-ins' but the error persists

Thank you.

Comment: In your target platform the `org.apache.lucene.core` plug-in/bundle (containing all mentioned missing packages of the same version as the plug-in/bundle) is missing.

Comment: How do fix that though? I tried installing org.apache.lucene.core 7.1.0 off the eclipse website and now my entire eclipse software no longer launches uh oh